# ASP.net VB DetailsView insert : javascript Postback on Cancel issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net, insert, detailsview

In my ASP.net  application, using ItemInserting on a Detailsview, 
I am using a javascript function to display an confirm box to the user. The confirm box basically displays the result of a query from the database.

THis works fine, except that postback ooccurs even if the users click cancel.

Im sure I am missing something elementary here , can the experts help? Your response is appreciated. I did search all over the site, but most of the solutions use an onClick event on a button. I am not sure how to make that work here.

Update: based on TheGeekYouNeed suggestion, I tried putting in a condition in my script. Now the popup does not come up anymore. Anyone?

```
 Protected Sub CustomerDetail_ItemInserting(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsViewInsertEventArgs)
    Dim args As String = e.Values("WriteID").ToString()

    For Each drv As Data.DataRowView In SqlDataSource3.[Select](DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty)
        If drv("WriteID") = args Then


            Dim ConnString As String = "Data Source=75409CHQ4034\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ExpenseTracker;Integrated Security=True"
            Dim SQLConn As New SqlConnection()
            Dim SQLCmd As New SqlCommand()
            Dim SQLdr As SqlDataReader

            SQLConn.ConnectionString = ConnString 'Set the Connection String
            SQLConn.Open() 'Open the connection
            SQLCmd.Connection = SQLConn 'Sets the Connection to use with the SQL Command
            SQLCmd.CommandText = "Select  Top 1 Budget - Difference as 'Remaining' FROM ExpenseImageAudit where WriteID =" + "'" + args + "' Group by ID, Budget-Difference order by ID desc "

            'Sets the SQL String
            SQLdr = SQLCmd.ExecuteReader 'Gets Data

            While SQLdr.Read() 'While Data is Present

                TextBox8.Text = SQLdr("Remaining")

                Dim script As String = String.Format("<script type='text/javascript'>confirmBudget({0});</script>", TextBox8.Text)
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.[GetType](), "script", script)
            End While
        SQLdr.Close() 'Close the SQLDataReader
        SQLConn.Close() 'Close the connection

        End If

    Next
End Sub
```

Script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function confirmBudget(amount) {
        return confirm('Based on your last transaction, your amount left is' + amount + '. Do you want to proceed?');
    }        
</script>
```

Comment: return false when user clicks on cancel to prevent postback

Comment: Not sure how to do that. Can you give an example?

Comment: **Dim script As String = "<script language='javascript'>var a=' " + TextBox8.Text & "'; if {!confirm('Based on your last transaction, your amount left is '+ a + ' Do you want to proceed?')); return false </script>"**
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.[GetType](), "script", script)**

Comment: you cant just return false everytime. TheGeekYouNeed's answer should work.

Comment: Well, its not working. :)  This doesnt work either: 'Dim script As String = "<script language='javascript'>var a=' " + TextBox8.Text & "'; if {!confirm('Based on your last transaction, your amount left is '+ a + ' Do you want to proceed?')) return false; else return true </script>"
                    'Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.[GetType](), "script", script)

Comment: That's not the answer I gave.  You revised the javascript. It's wrong.  Use exactly what I put.

Comment: Dim script As String = "<script language='javascript'>var a=' " + TextBox8.Text & "'; var answer = confirm('Based on your last transaction, your amount left is '+ a + '. Do you want to proceed?'); return answer; </script>"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this script in the head section of your aspx page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function confirmBudget(amount)
   {
      if(confirm('Based on your last transaction, your amount left is' + amount + '. Do you want to proceed?'))
      {
         document.getElementById("btnDoSomethingOnOK").click();
      }

   }
</script>
```

Call it like this from your server side code:

```
string script = string.Format("<script type='text/javascript'>confirmBudget({0});</script>", TextBox8.Text);

Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", script);
```

Sorry for the C# syntax. I dont know vb.

Comment: Asdfg, i tried your solution. I dont get any errors and the popup comes up but the value is again posted into the database on clicking cancel. Updated code above.

Comment: What does btnDoSomethingOnOK refer to? Since this is a DeailsView form, would it be the insert button?

Comment: its the dummy button that you may want to execute if user clicks "Ok"

Answer (score 1):

In your Javascript, return answer.

```
Dim script As String = "<script language='javascript'>var a=' " + TextBox8.Text & "'; var answer = confirm('Based on your last transaction, your amount left is '+ a + '. Do you want to proceed?'); return answer; </script>"
```

Comment: Return answer is not working. Now the popup does not come up at all and the debugger error is "return statement outside function"

Comment: While SQLdr.Read() 
                 TextBox8.Text = SQLdr("Remaining") '
               Dim script As String = "<script language='javascript'>var a=' " + TextBox8.Text & "'; var answer = confirm('Your budget is '+ a); return answer; </script>"
                 Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.[GetType](), "script", script) 
            End While

Comment: The statement is part of the script...do i need to declare elsewhere?

Comment: TheGeekYouNeed , thanks for your reply. I edited it because i was getting the  "return statement outside function" error. I used your edited version again and am still getting that error.